# MIME message not being correctly displayed in Mac Email client

Tags: mime-types, mime, email-client, mime-message, mime-mail

I am generating a multi-part mime email message from code.  An example of the mime format I am using is shown below.  This displays just fine in most email clients, but in Apple Email on a Mac then the message just says "This message has no content".  Can anyone shed any light on why Mail on a Mac cannot display the message below?

Thanks very much.

```
X-SYSTEM-Source: 0BC1ACEB-5527-42BF-A618-814EBB750F59
x-virtual-mta: zzzstandardmta
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: ScanTest <ScanTest@xxxxxx.com>
To: Jane Doe <janedoe@zzzzzz.com>
Date: 25 Jun 2014 15:42:26 +0100
Subject: Generic ScanTest Email
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--mainboundary_67d1fe5e-6a7f-4c46-818d-9a33a6abddf1
Message-ID: <199999-19999908ies800000016@webserver.vvvvvvvvv.co.uk>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 25 Jun 2014 14:42:26.0632 (UTC) FILETIME=[AEE3E480:01CF9083]
X-Original-To: janedoe@zzzzzz.com
X-Virus-Scanned: ClamAV using ClamSMTP


----mainboundary_67d1fe5e-6a7f-4c46-818d-9a33a6abddf1
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=--altboundary_67d1fe5e-6a7f-4c46-818d-9a33a6abddf1


----altboundary_67d1fe5e-6a7f-4c46-818d-9a33a6abddf1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


This is ScanTest from 

Dear Jane<br /><br />This is a test email.  Does it look ok?<br /><br />Here is some more blurb. One of the things about this text is that it is not in Latin. Here is some more blurb. One of the things about this text is that it is not in Latin. Here is some more blurb. One of the things about this text is that it is not in Latin. Here is some more blurb. One of the things about this text is that it is not in Latin.<br />Here is some more blurb. One of the things about this text is that it is not in Latin.<br />Here is some more blurb. One of the things about this text is that it is not in Latin<br /><br />Here is some more blurb. One of the things about this text is that it is not in Latin<br />Here is some more blurb. One of the things about this text is that it is not in Latin<br />Here is some more blurb. One of the things about this text is that it is not in Latin



Thanks from the team

----altboundary_67d1fe5e-6a7f-4c46-818d-9a33a6abddf1
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBYSFRNTCAxLjAgVHJhbnNpdGlvbmFsLy9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL1RSL3hodG1sMS9EVEQveGh0bWwxLXRyYW5zaXRpb25hbC5kdGQiPg0KPGh0bWwgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGh0bWwiPg0KPGhlYWQ+DQogICAgPG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0L2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9aXNvLTg4NTktMSIgLz4NCiAgICA8dGl0bGU+U2NhblRlc3QgLSA8L3RpdGxlPg0KICAgIDxzdHlsZSB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2NzcyI+DQoJCTwhLS0NCgkJYm9keSB7DQoJCQljb2xvcjogIzMzMzMzMzsNCgkJCWZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OiBWZXJkYW5hLCBHZW5ldmEsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7DQoJCQlmb250LXNpemU6IDEycHg7DQoJCX0NCgkJYSB7DQoJCQlib3JkZXI6IDA7CQ0KCQl9DQoJCWEgaW1nIHsNCgkJCWJvcmRlcjogMDsJDQoJCX0NCgkJcCB7DQoJCQlwYWRkaW5nOiAwIDEwcHggMCAxMHB4Ow0KCQl9DQoJCWgxIHsNCgkJCXBhZGRpbmc6IDAgMTBweCAwIDEwcHg7DQoJCQlmb250LWZhbWlseTogVmVyZGFuYSwgR2VuZXZhLCBzYW5zLXNlcmlmOw0KCQkJZm9udC1zaXplOiAyMHB4Ow0KCQkJY29sb3I6ICMzMzMzMzM7DQoJCQlsaW5lLWhlaWdodDogMTUwJTsNCgkJfQ0KCQlpbWcgew0KCQkJdmVydGljYWwtYWxpZ246IG1pZGRsZTsJDQoJCX0NCgkJLmNvbnRlbnQgew0KCQkJZm9udC1mYW1pbHk6IFZlcmRhbmEsIEdlbmV2YSwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZjsNCgkJCWZvbnQtc2l6ZTogMTJweDsNCgkJCWNvbG9yOiAjMzMzMzMzOwkNCgkJCWxpbmUtaGVpZ2h0OiAxNTAlOw0KCQl9DQoJCXAubG9nbyB7DQoJCQlwYWRkaW5nLXJpZ2h0OiAxNXB4Ow0KCQl9DQoJCXAuZm9vdGVyIHsNCgkJCXBhZGRpbmc6IDAgMTBweCAwIDEwcHg7DQoJCQlmb250LWZhbWlseTogVmVyZGFuYSwgR2VuZXZhLCBzYW5zLXNlcmlmOw0KCQkJZm9udC1zaXplOiAxMHB4Ow0KCQkJY29sb3I6ICMzMzMzMzM7DQoJCQlsaW5lLWhlaWdodDogMTUwJTsNCgkJfQ0KCQlhOmxpbmssIGE6dmlzaXRlZCB7DQoJCQljb2xvcjogIzAwNjY5OTsNCgkJCXRleHQtZGVjb3JhdGlvbjogbm9uZTsNCgkJfQ0KCQlhOmhvdmVyIHsNCgkJCXRleHQtZGVjb3JhdGlvbjogdW5kZXJsaW5lOw0KCQl9DQoJCS50YWJsZS1ib3JkZXIgew0KCQkJYm9yZGVyOiAwOw0KCQkJcGFkZGluZzogMTBweCAwIDEwcHggMDsNCgkJfQ0KCQktLT4NCiAgICA8L3N0eWxlPg0KPC9oZWFkPg0KPGJvZHk+DQogICAgPHRhYmxlIHdpZHRoPSI2MDAiIGJvcmRlcj0iMCIgY2xhc3M9InRhYmxlLWJvcmRlciIgYWxpZ249ImNlbnRlciIgY2VsbHBhZGRpbmc9IjAiIGNlbGxzcGFjaW5nPSIwIj4NCiAgICAgICAgPHRyPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgPHRkIHZhbGlnbj0idG9wIj4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgIAk8cD48aW1nIHNyYz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5hdG9taWNjcm0uY29tL0ltYWdlc2VydmVyL0xvZ28vU2NhblRlc3QiIC8+DQogICAgICAgICAgICAJPC9wPg0KICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGQ+DQogICAgICAgICAgICA8dGQgYWxpZ249InJpZ2h0IiB2YWxpZ249InRvcCI+DQogICAgICAgICAgICAJPHAgY2xhc3M9ImxvZ28iPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAk8IS0tPGltZyBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly90cmFkZXNob3cubWt0cG9pbnQuY29tL0ltYWdlc2VydmVyL0xvZ28vW1tTaG93TG9nby5naWZdXSIgaGVpZ2h0PSI3NSIgIC8+LS0+DQoJCQkJPC9wPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgPC90ZD4NCiAgICAgICAgPC90cj4NCiAgICAgICAgPHRyPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgPHRkIGNvbHNwYW49IjIiIGNsYXNzPSJjb250ZW50Ij4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8aDE+VGhpcyBpcyBTY2FuVGVzdCBmcm9tIDwvaDE+DQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgDQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPHA+RGVhciBKYW5lPGJyIC8+PGJyIC8+VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgZW1haWwuICBEb2VzIGl0IGxvb2sgb2s/PGJyIC8+PGJyIC8+SGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIG1vcmUgYmx1cmIuIE9uZSBvZiB0aGUgdGhpbmdzIGFib3V0IHRoaXMgdGV4dCBpcyB0aGF0IGl0IGlzIG5vdCBpbiBMYXRpbi4gSGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIG1vcmUgYmx1cmIuIE9uZSBvZiB0aGUgdGhpbmdzIGFib3V0IHRoaXMgdGV4dCBpcyB0aGF0IGl0IGlzIG5vdCBpbiBMYXRpbi4gSGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIG1vcmUgYmx1cmIuIE9uZSBvZiB0aGUgdGhpbmdzIGFib3V0IHRoaXMgdGV4dCBpcyB0aGF0IGl0IGlzIG5vdCBpbiBMYXRpbi4gSGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIG1vcmUgYmx1cmIuIE9uZSBvZiB0aGUgdGhpbmdzIGFib3V0IHRoaXMgdGV4dCBpcyB0aGF0IGl0IGlzIG5vdCBpbiBMYXRpbi48YnIgLz5IZXJlIGlzIHNvbWUgbW9yZSBibHVyYi4gT25lIG9mIHRoZSB0aGluZ3MgYWJvdXQgdGhpcyB0ZXh0IGlzIHRoYXQgaXQgaXMgbm90IGluIExhdGluLjxiciAvPkhlcmUgaXMgc29tZSBtb3JlIGJsdXJiLiBPbmUgb2YgdGhlIHRoaW5ncyBhYm91dCB0aGlzIHRleHQgaXMgdGhhdCBpdCBpcyBub3QgaW4gTGF0aW48YnIgLz48YnIgLz5IZXJlIGlzIHNvbWUgbW9yZSBibHVyYi4gT25lIG9mIHRoZSB0aGluZ3MgYWJvdXQgdGhpcyB0ZXh0IGlzIHRoYXQgaXQgaXMgbm90IGluIExhdGluPGJyIC8+SGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIG1vcmUgYmx1cmIuIE9uZSBvZiB0aGUgdGhpbmdzIGFib3V0IHRoaXMgdGV4dCBpcyB0aGF0IGl0IGlzIG5vdCBpbiBMYXRpbjxiciAvPkhlcmUgaXMgc29tZSBtb3JlIGJsdXJiLiBPbmUgb2YgdGhlIHRoaW5ncyBhYm91dCB0aGlzIHRleHQgaXMgdGhhdCBpdCBpcyBub3QgaW4gTGF0aW48L3A+DQoNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8cD48L3A+DQoNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8cD5UaGFua3MgZnJvbSB0aGUgdGVhbTwvcD4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgIA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxociB3aWR0aD0iOTYlIiAvPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAk8YnIgLz4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICANCg0KDQogICAgICAgICAgICA8L3RkPg0KICAgICAgICA8L3RyPg0KICAgIDwvdGFibGU+DQo8L2JvZHk+DQo8L2h0bWw+

----altboundary_67d1fe5e-6a7f-4c46-818d-9a33a6abddf1--

----mainboundary_67d1fe5e-6a7f-4c46-818d-9a33a6abddf1--
```

Answer (score 0):

The Base64-encoded data is over 4000 characters on a single line. This needs to be split into shorter lines. This is what [RFC5322 "Internet Message Format"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.1.1) has to say about line length:

> **2.1.1.  Line Length Limits**
>
> There are two limits that this specification places on the number of    characters in a line.  **Each line of characters MUST be no more than 998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding the CRLF.**
>
> The 998 character limit is due to limitations in many implementations that send, receive, or store IMF messages which simply cannot handle more than 998 characters on a line.  Receiving implementations would do well to handle an arbitrarily large number of characters in a line for robustness sake.  However, **there are so many implementations that** (in compliance with the transport requirements of [[RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)]) **do not accept messages containing more than 1000 characters including the CR and LF** per line, it is important for implementations not to create such messages.

Also, make sure that line endings that are terminating headers and surrounding delimiters are actually `CRLF`, and that they closely follow the MIME syntax described in [RFC 2046 "MIME Part Two: Media Types"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046). Excerpt (BNF Syntax, somewhat simplified):

```
multipart-body := [preamble CRLF]
                  dash-boundary CRLF
                  body-part *encapsulation
                  close-delimiter
                  [CRLF epilogue]

dash-boundary := "--" boundary

body-part := MIME-part-headers [CRLF *OCTET]

encapsulation := delimiter
                 CRLF body-part

delimiter := CRLF dash-boundary

close-delimiter := delimiter "--"
```